# rails routes "uninitialized constant CoursesController"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I'm working in a rails project and I add the following route:

```
get '/courses/:invitation_code'       =>  "courses#find_invitation"
```

On my controller I have the following action:

```
def find_invitation
    @course = Course.where(["invitation_code = ?", params[:invitation_code]])
    if !@course.empty?
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json {  render json: @course, success: true, error: false  }
        end
    end
end
```

But, when I try to go to localhost:3000/course/demo123 I get the following error:

> ActionController::RoutingError at /courses/demo123 uninitialized
>   constant CoursesController

And I don't understand why. This a project with devise and a new in this project, so I don;t know if I have to do something else, in order to make this action work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the name of your controller?

Comment: class Admin::CoursesController < Admin::ApplicationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify controller's namespace in your route.

Try changing:

```
get '/courses/:invitation_code'       =>  "courses#find_invitation"
```

to:

```
get '/courses/:invitation_code'       => 'admin/courses#find_invitation'
```

Comment: If I made that change, I don't get the error, but I being redirected to my '/landing' page :s

Comment: @Jean Probably another issue, unrelated to this one. Maybe you have a `before_filter` in `Admin::ApplicationController` that performs redirection. You probably can find all info you need in your app's log.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
match '/courses/invitation_code'       =>  "courses#find_invitation"
```

Answer (score -1):

convert your root as follows

```
match '/courses/:invitation_code'       =>  "courses#find_invitation"
```

The url must be with the segment id as follows

localhost:3000/courses/demo123

Comment: It's probably OP's mistake in question, not actual issue with the code. The problem is `CoursesController` seems to be missing.